# is it possible return different type of object

Tags: iphone

I have a function in which I hope to return different type

```
-(UIButton *)returnObject1 ;
{

    //dosomething

    return aUIButton;

}

-(UIView *)returnObject2 ;
{

    //dosomething

    return aUIView;
}
```

I hope to merge the two function to one and return different NSObject(UIButton,UIView)
Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Comment: Actually yes, do you mean return 2 objects or return the object depending on the type you receie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't declare a return type. Change it to this instead:

```
- (id)returnObject
{
  if (something) {
    return aUIButton;
  }

  return aUIView;
}
```

However... `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`, which means you can do this instead:

```
- (UIView *)returnObject
{
  if (something) {
    return aUIButton;
  }

  return aUIView;
}
```

Note that, in objective-c, the return type of a method is completely irrelevant while the code is being executed. The entire purpose is to inform the compiler what your code expects, so that it can avoid crashes. So, specifying a return type is a good idea when possible, but is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create your own custom object that contains both and return that one

Edit: I understood that the OP wanted to return 2 objects. this answer only applies for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you want:

```
-(id)returnObject:(int)type
{
    if (type == 1)
        return aUIButton;
    else if (type == 2)
        return aUIView;
    return nil;
}
```